# How to check if a window style exists in a hexadecimal?

Tags: winapi, window-style

I have a question regarding a window style hexadecimal.

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/111011/en-us, `0x16CF0000` contains window styles of `WS_VISIBLE`, `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS`, `WS_CLIPCHILDREN`, `WS_CAPTION`, `WS_SYSMENU`, `WS_THICKFRAME`, `WS_MINIMIZEBOX`, and `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX`.

How do I check if a window style exist in a combination of window styles? For example, I would like to check if `WS_BORDER` (`0x00800000`) style exists in `0x16CF0000`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard form with my bug fixed is:

```
if ((value & WS_BORDER) != 0) {  }
```

The & will do a bitwise-AND and only if the bit of WS_BORDER is set will the result be non-zero

Comment: I am sure this answer is technically wrong. Equality operators have greater precedence than Bitwise Operators. Requires parenthesis.

Comment: Quite right. I didn't compile this (in my head or otherwise).  But it's a small typo that hasn't bothered anyone for 12 years. Feel free to [edit].

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you can just check whether `yourValue AND WS_BORDER = WS_BORDER`.

Unfortunately, some of the bits inside of the style flags are used twice, depending on context, so for example both `WS_TABSTOP` and `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX` are 0x00010000, so it depends on the context (position of the object and maybe other flags) whether a window really has that property (while a parent control cannot have a tab stop, a child control sometimes can have a maximize box)...

```
WS_OVERLAPPED      = 0x00000000,
WS_POPUP           = 0x80000000,
WS_CHILD           = 0x40000000,
WS_MINIMIZE        = 0x20000000,
WS_VISIBLE         = 0x10000000,
WS_DISABLED        = 0x08000000,
WS_CLIPSIBLINGS    = 0x04000000,
WS_CLIPCHILDREN    = 0x02000000,
WS_MAXIMIZE        = 0x01000000,
WS_BORDER          = 0x00800000,
WS_DLGFRAME        = 0x00400000,
WS_VSCROLL         = 0x00200000,
WS_HSCROLL         = 0x00100000,
WS_SYSMENU         = 0x00080000,
WS_THICKFRAME      = 0x00040000,
WS_GROUP           = 0x00020000,
WS_TABSTOP         = 0x00010000,

WS_MINIMIZEBOX     = 0x00020000,
WS_MAXIMIZEBOX     = 0x00010000,

WS_CAPTION         = WS_BORDER | WS_DLGFRAME,
WS_TILED           = WS_OVERLAPPED,
WS_ICONIC          = WS_MINIMIZE,
WS_SIZEBOX         = WS_THICKFRAME,
WS_TILEDWINDOW     = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,

WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW    = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | 
                         WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,
WS_POPUPWINDOW     = WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER | WS_SYSMENU,
WS_CHILDWINDOW     = WS_CHILD,
```

Comment: This answer has inaccuracy. child windows can indeed have MaximizeBox, CloseBox and MinimizeBox.

Comment: @user13947194 Thanks for the feedback. Do you know how these cases can be distinguished; only possible by window class ("Edit" or "Button" cannot have maximize box, but "MDIClient" can)?

Comment: Uhm. Edit and Button and every other child class can have maximize box. style = WS_CAPTION|WS_SYSMENU|WS_MAXIMIZEBOX. No I sadly have no solution. I have no clue why Microsoft has done this. Alot of times one style has two names eg: WS_CHILD/WS_CHILDWINDOW, WS_OVERLAPPED/WS_TILED. Another hypothesis is that WS_TABSTOP only works if the child window has no caption. But I cant get tabstop to work in real life. WS_TABSTOP might even be a style that only works in dialogs.

Comment: @user13947194 Out of curiosity: Do you have a screenshot how it looks when a child Button has a maximize box? And what happens when anyone dares to click it?

Comment: I tested it on winXp and win7. Just create a main window and create a button as its child and apply the style I showed you.(WS_CAPTION|WS_SYSMENU|WS_MAXIMIZEBOX)

Comment: @user13947194 Tried it on Win10, and setting that styles had no visual effect. Maybe C# somehow messes with the styles. My code is here: https://gist.github.com/schierlm/34fdb1e22428983c98af8b6947403dca

Comment: I left a comment on the github page so sent me.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(0x16CF0000 & WS_BORDER)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `IF((0x16CF0000 | WS_BORDER) == 0x16CF0000)`

Comment: This method of simply testing if a style exists in a number is presumptive and is not documented. As some styles share bits but are exclusive. Example CBS_SIMPLE=1 CBS_DROPDOWN=2 CBS_DROPDOWNLIST=3 as you can see share bits, but CBS_SIMPLE is not CBS_DROPDOWN is not CBS_DROPDOWNLIST. WS_BORDER however is one of those styles that doesn't seem to share bits. So you really need context when doing this test. winapi should have created a function to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I have taken the header file where such things were defined and wrote a script to turn it into code that would take the Variable which the flags were and convert it into a text string containing the symbolic name of the constants.

Parsing #defines is rather easy back in the day I used something like AWK to do this.  Now days, if I have it on the machine I'm using at the time, Python or if Python's not readily available I'd drop back to AWK.

Answer (score 0):

This question really concerned me as I was creating a win32 dialog builder. One of the features was setting the style of all win32 common controls, and also user defined controls. I have learnt alot via observation, and the little documentation provided by MSDN; and I wish to share my information. Which will go beyond answering this question.

How did the Microsoft team format their window styles?

1. Their are general window styles that applies to all windows. They begin with 'WS_' and are found in the high order bits. 0xffff0000.
2. Then there are Control specific/ user defined styles that begin with their specified prefix. Such as BS for ButtonStyle, CBS for ComboBoxStyle, and so on. They are found in the low order bits. 0x0000ffff.

There are 5 types in these two levels of styles:

1. Default - These kinds of style are equal to zero. This style is only chosen if
   style is equal to zero.
2. flag - These kinds of style never equates to zero, and are placed on unique
   bits. Meaning that these styles can be used simultaneously.
3. exclusive - These kinds of styles normally share bits with each other. But this doesn't have to be the case as WS_POPUP and WS_CHILD are exclusive but they don't share bits. Most other styles such as CBS_SIMPLE and CBS_DROPDOWN are exclusive and indeed share bits. Exclusive styles often represent a category. BS_OWNERDRAW, BS_RADIOBUTTON, BS_PUSHBUTTON all represent the type of button category. BS_CENTER, BS_LEFT, BS_TOP are the alignment category. Note that BS_PUSHBUTTON is equal to zero and represents the Default for the type category.
4. compound - These kinds of styles are comprised of multiply styles. Such as WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, WS_POPUPWINDOW, DS_SHELLFONT, LBS_STANDARD.
5. synonym - These kinds of styles refer to the same thing. Eg: WS_CHILDWINDOW vs WS_CHILD, WS_TILED vs WS_OVERLAPPED, WS_TILEDWINDOW vs WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW. Note that WS_TABSTOP and WS_MAXIMIZEBOX share the same value but they are not synonymns as they are semantically different. How? This is outside my scope of knowledge. WS_TABSTOP is applied to controls used in a dialog and the dialog implements the right behaviour. However, you can use isDialogMessage to simulate the same behaviour outside of a dialog. And child windows can have maximize box. For my application, I completely ignored WS_TABSTOP style.

How do we test for a style?
I created a function that converts a style to string. However, a function that test if a style exists in another style might be impractical, as this requires alot of context. A sample function prototype would look as follows...

```
/** \param className - use WC_DIALOG for dialog window
                       use NULL for top level window
*/
bool hasWindowStyle(const char *className,UINT style,UINT requiredStyle);
```

className would be used as the major context. If className is WC_DIALOG, then all of the DS_* styles are available to the window. But it cannot have styles that belong to the button class, edit class, etc. Problem is, the following is technically wrong...

```
return (style & requiredStyle) == requiredStyle;
```

This is faulty because, even if requiredStyle exist in style, doesnt mean that requiredStyle is a valid style for the particular className. This would require us to have a map of all styles of the particular class, and only if requiredStyle exist in that map, return the above formula.

```
std::map<std::string,UINT> win32_class_list;

auto elem = win32_class_list.find(className);
auto invalid = win32_class_list.end();

if(elem == invalid) return false;
else return (style & requiredStyle) == requiredStyle;
```

The above solved the first problem. But the last problem seems impractical to solve. Lets say you have a required style which is CBS_SIMPLE|CBS_LOWERCASE. How would you determine if this required style was apart of the combobox's style. This is a very contextual question.

Check out my Part 2 for a function that converts window style to string.

Answer (score 0):

***PART 2***

A genaral function for converting a window style to string. Hope this is useful to some one. Note that due to space, you will have to implement the following two function prototypes.

Jav/string/builder.h

```
/** \brief builds a string from parts and appends it to result.
    \param result
    \param format a format string similar to sprintf, except that '?' is 
           the only format specifier. C++ template system automatically
           deduces the type and count of format specifiers.
    \param arg first argument of parameter pack is always const char* in
           this case.
    \param REST... rest of parts. Can support any and every C++ type.  
  */
template<class ...REST>
void buildString(std::string &result,const char *format,const char *arg,REST...);
```

Jav/string/numconv.h

```
/** \brief converts num to a hexidecimal string consisting of a
           hexidecimal prefix '0x'.  
  */
const char* hex_string(uint num);
```

win_styles.cpp

```
namespace {

enum { USER_DEFINED_STYLE_MASK = 0xffff };

struct ClassNameCompare
{
    bool operator()(const char *lhs,const char *rhs)
    {
     return strcmp(lhs,rhs) < 0;
    }
};

using Win32StyleExpert = void(*)(std::string&,uint,const char*);
using Win32ClassList = std::map<const char*,Win32StyleExpert,ClassNameCompare>;

extern Win32ClassList win32_class_list;

Win32StyleExpert getWin32StyleExpert(const char *className)
{
 auto elem = win32_class_list.find(className);
 return elem == win32_class_list.end() ? NULL : &elem->second;
}

}

std::string windowStyleToString(const char *className,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    std::string s;

    if( (style & WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW) == WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW ) buildString(s,"??","WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW",sep);
    else
    {
     if( (style & WS_SIZEBOX) == WS_SIZEBOX ) buildString(s,"??","WS_SIZEBOX",sep);
     if( (style & WS_MINIMIZEBOX) == WS_MINIMIZEBOX )   buildString(s,"??","WS_MINIMIZEBOX",sep);
     if( (style & WS_MAXIMIZEBOX) == WS_MAXIMIZEBOX )   buildString(s,"??","WS_MAXIMIZEBOX",sep);
     if( (style & WS_SYSMENU) == WS_SYSMENU )   buildString(s,"??","WS_SYSMENU",sep);

     if( (style & WS_CAPTION) == WS_CAPTION )   buildString(s,"??","WS_CAPTION",sep);
     else if( (style & WS_BORDER) == WS_BORDER )    buildString(s,"??","WS_BORDER",sep);
    }

    if( (style & WS_CHILD) == WS_CHILD )buildString(s,"??","WS_CHILD",sep);
    else if( (style & WS_POPUP) == WS_POPUP ) buildString(s,"??","WS_POPUP",sep);

    if( (style & WS_MINIMIZE) == WS_MINIMIZE )  buildString(s,"??","WS_MINIMIZE",sep);
    if( (style & WS_MAXIMIZE) == WS_MAXIMIZE )  buildString(s,"??","WS_MAXIMIZE",sep);
    if( (style & WS_DISABLED) ==  WS_DISABLED)  buildString(s,"??","WS_DISABLED",sep);
    if( (style & WS_HSCROLL) ==  WS_HSCROLL)    buildString(s,"??","WS_HSCROLL",sep);
    if( (style & WS_VSCROLL) ==  WS_VSCROLL)    buildString(s,"??","WS_VSCROLL",sep);
    if( (style & WS_VISIBLE) ==  WS_VISIBLE)    buildString(s,"??","WS_VISIBLE",sep);

    if( (style & WS_DLGFRAME) ==  WS_DLGFRAME && (style & WS_CAPTION) != WS_CAPTION)
            buildString(s,"??","WS_DLGFRAME",sep);


    if((int)className == (int)WC_DIALOG)
    {
        if( (style & DS_SHELLFONT) == DS_SHELLFONT ) buildString(s,"??","DS_SHELLFONT",sep);
        else
        {
         if( (style & DS_FIXEDSYS) == DS_FIXEDSYS ) buildString(s,"??","DS_FIXEDSYS",sep);
         if( (style & DS_SETFONT) == DS_SETFONT )   buildString(s,"??","DS_SETFONT",sep);
        }

        if( (style & DS_ABSALIGN) == DS_ABSALIGN )  buildString(s,"??","DS_ABSALIGN",sep);
        if( (style & DS_CENTER) == DS_CENTER )  buildString(s,"??","DS_CENTER",sep);
        if( (style & DS_CENTERMOUSE) == DS_CENTERMOUSE )    buildString(s,"??","DS_CENTERMOUSE",sep);
        if( (style & DS_CONTEXTHELP) == DS_CONTEXTHELP )    buildString(s,"??","DS_CONTEXTHELP",sep);
        if( (style & DS_CONTROL) == DS_CONTROL )    buildString(s,"??","DS_CONTROL",sep);
        if( (style & DS_LOCALEDIT) == DS_LOCALEDIT )    buildString(s,"??","DS_LOCALEDIT",sep);
        if( (style & DS_MODALFRAME) == DS_MODALFRAME )  buildString(s,"??","DS_MODALFRAME",sep);
        if( (style & DS_NOFAILCREATE) == DS_NOFAILCREATE )  buildString(s,"??","DS_NOFAILCREATE",sep);
        if( (style & DS_SETFOREGROUND) == DS_SETFOREGROUND )    buildString(s,"??","DS_SETFOREGROUND",sep);
    }
    else if(auto pushStyle = getWin32StyleExpert(className))
    {
     if(style == 0) return "0";
     else pushStyle(s,style,sep);
    }
    else if( style == WS_OVERLAPPED ) return "WS_OVERLAPPED";
    else if(className == NULL) buildString(s,"??",Jav::hex_str(style&USER_DEFINED_STYLE_MASK),sep);

    if(s.empty()) return "";

    s.pop_back(); //remove the last seperator added
    return s;
}

namespace {

void pushAnimateControlStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & ACS_AUTOPLAY) == ACS_AUTOPLAY )    buildString(s,"??","ACS_AUTOPLAY",sep);
    if( (style & ACS_CENTER) == ACS_CENTER )    buildString(s,"??","ACS_CENTER",sep);
    if( (style & ACS_TIMER) == ACS_TIMER )  buildString(s,"??","ACS_TIMER",sep);
}

void pushButtonStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & 0xf) == BS_3STATE )buildString(s,"??","BS_3STATE",sep);
    else if( (style & 0xf) == BS_AUTO3STATE )   buildString(s,"??","BS_AUTO3STATE",sep);
    else if( (style & 0xf) == BS_AUTOCHECKBOX ) buildString(s,"??","BS_AUTOCHECKBOX",sep);
    else if( (style & 0xf) == BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON )  buildString(s,"??","BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON",sep);
    else if( (style & 0xf) == BS_CHECKBOX ) buildString(s,"??","BS_CHECKBOX",sep);
    else if( (style & 0xf) == BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON )    buildString(s,"??","BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON",sep);
    else if( (style & 0xf) == BS_GROUPBOX ) buildString(s,"??","BS_GROUPBOX",sep);
    else if( (style & 0xf) == BS_OWNERDRAW )    buildString(s,"??","BS_OWNERDRAW",sep);
    else if( (style & 0xf) == BS_RADIOBUTTON )  buildString(s,"??","BS_RADIOBUTTON",sep);
    else buildString(s,"??","BS_PUSHBUTTON",sep);

    if( (style & 0xc0) == BS_BITMAP )buildString(s,"??","BS_BITMAP",sep);
    else if( (style & 0xc0) == BS_ICON )buildString(s,"??","BS_ICON",sep);
    else buildString(s,"??","BS_TEXT",sep);

    if( (style & 0xf00) == BS_CENTER )buildString(s,"??","BS_CENTER",sep);
    else if( (style & 0xf00) == BS_VCENTER )    buildString(s,"??","BS_VCENTER",sep);
    else if( (style & 0xf00) == BS_LEFT )buildString(s,"??","BS_LEFT",sep);
    else if( (style & 0xf00) == BS_TOP )buildString(s,"??","BS_TOP",sep);
    else if( (style & 0xf00) == BS_RIGHT )buildString(s,"??","BS_RIGHT",sep);
    else if( (style & 0xf00) == BS_BOTTOM )buildString(s,"??","BS_BOTTOM",sep);

    if( (style & BS_FLAT) == BS_FLAT )buildString(s,"??","BS_FLAT",sep);
    if( (style & BS_MULTILINE) == BS_MULTILINE )    buildString(s,"??","BS_MULTILINE",sep);
    if( (style & BS_NOTIFY) == BS_NOTIFY )buildString(s,"??","BS_NOTIFY",sep);
    if( (style & BS_PUSHLIKE) == BS_PUSHLIKE )  buildString(s,"??","BS_PUSHLIKE",sep);
    if( (style & BS_LEFTTEXT) == BS_LEFTTEXT )  buildString(s,"??","BS_LEFTTEXT",sep);
}

void pushComboBoxExStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & CBES_EX_CASESENSITIVE) == CBES_EX_CASESENSITIVE )  buildString(s,"??","CBES_EX_CASESENSITIVE",sep);
    if( (style & CBES_EX_NOEDITIMAGE) == CBES_EX_NOEDITIMAGE )  buildString(s,"??","CBES_EX_NOEDITIMAGE",sep);
    if( (style & CBES_EX_NOEDITIMAGEINDENT) == CBES_EX_NOEDITIMAGEINDENT )  buildString(s,"??","CBES_EX_NOEDITIMAGEINDENT",sep);
    if( (style & CBES_EX_NOSIZELIMIT) == CBES_EX_NOSIZELIMIT )  buildString(s,"??","CBES_EX_NOSIZELIMIT",sep);
    if( (style & CBES_EX_PATHWORDBREAKPROC) == CBES_EX_PATHWORDBREAKPROC )  buildString(s,"??","CBES_EX_PATHWORDBREAKPROC",sep);
}

void pushComboBoxStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & 3) == CBS_SIMPLE )buildString(s,"??","CBS_SIMPLE",sep);
    else if( (style & 3) == CBS_DROPDOWN )  buildString(s,"??","CBS_DROPDOWN",sep);
    else if( (style & 3) == CBS_DROPDOWNLIST )  buildString(s,"??","CBS_DROPDOWNLIST",sep);

    if( (style & 0x30) == CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED )  buildString(s,"??","CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED",sep);
    else if( (style & 0x30) == CBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE )  buildString(s,"??","CBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE",sep);

    if( (style & 0x6000) == CBS_LOWERCASE ) buildString(s,"??","CBS_LOWERCASE",sep);
    else if( (style & 0x6000) == CBS_UPPERCASE )    buildString(s,"??","CBS_UPPERCASE",sep);

    if( (style & CBS_DISABLENOSCROLL) == CBS_DISABLENOSCROLL )  buildString(s,"??","CBS_DISABLENOSCROLL",sep);
    if( (style & CBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT) == CBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT )    buildString(s,"??","CBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT",sep);
    if( (style & CBS_SORT) == CBS_SORT )buildString(s,"??","CBS_SORT",sep);
    if( (style & CBS_AUTOHSCROLL) == CBS_AUTOHSCROLL )  buildString(s,"??","CBS_AUTOHSCROLL",sep);
    if( (style & CBS_OEMCONVERT) == CBS_OEMCONVERT )    buildString(s,"??","CBS_OEMCONVERT",sep);
}

void pushEditControlStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & 0x3) == ES_CENTER )buildString(s,"??","ES_CENTER",sep);
    else if( (style & 0x3) == ES_RIGHT )buildString(s,"??","ES_RIGHT",sep);

    if( (style & 0x18) == ES_LOWERCASE )    buildString(s,"??","ES_LOWERCASE",sep);
    else if( (style & 0x18) == ES_UPPERCASE )   buildString(s,"??","ES_UPPERCASE",sep);

    if( (style & ES_AUTOHSCROLL) == ES_AUTOHSCROLL )    buildString(s,"??","ES_AUTOHSCROLL",sep);
    if( (style & ES_AUTOVSCROLL) == ES_AUTOVSCROLL )    buildString(s,"??","ES_AUTOVSCROLL",sep);
    if( (style & ES_MULTILINE) == ES_MULTILINE )    buildString(s,"??","ES_MULTILINE",sep);
    if( (style & ES_NOHIDESEL) == ES_NOHIDESEL )    buildString(s,"??","ES_NOHIDESEL",sep);
    if( (style & ES_NUMBER) == ES_NUMBER )  buildString(s,"??","ES_NUMBER",sep);
    if( (style & ES_OEMCONVERT) == ES_OEMCONVERT )  buildString(s,"??","ES_OEMCONVERT",sep);
    if( (style & ES_PASSWORD) == ES_PASSWORD )  buildString(s,"??","ES_PASSWORD",sep);
    if( (style & ES_READONLY) == ES_READONLY )  buildString(s,"??","ES_READONLY",sep);
    if( (style & ES_WANTRETURN) == ES_WANTRETURN )  buildString(s,"??","ES_WANTRETURN",sep);
}

void pushHeaderControlStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & HDS_BUTTONS) == HDS_BUTTONS )  buildString(s,"??","HDS_BUTTONS",sep);
    if( (style & HDS_DRAGDROP) == HDS_DRAGDROP )    buildString(s,"??","HDS_DRAGDROP",sep);
    if( (style & HDS_FILTERBAR) == HDS_FILTERBAR )  buildString(s,"??","HDS_FILTERBAR",sep);
    if( (style & HDS_FULLDRAG) == HDS_FULLDRAG )    buildString(s,"??","HDS_FULLDRAG",sep);
    if( (style & HDS_HIDDEN) == HDS_HIDDEN )    buildString(s,"??","HDS_HIDDEN",sep);
    if( (style & HDS_HORZ) == HDS_HORZ )    buildString(s,"??","HDS_HORZ",sep);
    if( (style & HDS_HOTTRACK) == HDS_HOTTRACK )    buildString(s,"??","HDS_HOTTRACK",sep);
}

void pushListBoxStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & 0x30) == LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED )  buildString(s,"??","LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED",sep);
    else if( (style & 0x30) == LBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE )  buildString(s,"??","LBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE",sep);

    if( (style & LBS_DISABLENOSCROLL) == LBS_DISABLENOSCROLL )  buildString(s,"??","LBS_DISABLENOSCROLL",sep);
    if( (style & LBS_EXTENDEDSEL) == LBS_EXTENDEDSEL )  buildString(s,"??","LBS_EXTENDEDSEL",sep);
    if( (style & LBS_HASSTRINGS) == LBS_HASSTRINGS )    buildString(s,"??","LBS_HASSTRINGS",sep);
    if( (style & LBS_MULTICOLUMN) == LBS_MULTICOLUMN )  buildString(s,"??","LBS_MULTICOLUMN",sep);
    if( (style & LBS_MULTIPLESEL) == LBS_MULTIPLESEL )  buildString(s,"??","LBS_MULTIPLESEL",sep);
    if( (style & LBS_NODATA) == LBS_NODATA )    buildString(s,"??","LBS_NODATA",sep);
    if( (style & LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT) == LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT )    buildString(s,"??","LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT",sep);
    if( (style & LBS_NOREDRAW) == LBS_NOREDRAW )    buildString(s,"??","LBS_NOREDRAW",sep);
    if( (style & LBS_NOSEL) == LBS_NOSEL )  buildString(s,"??","LBS_NOSEL",sep);
    if( (style & LBS_NOTIFY) == LBS_NOTIFY )    buildString(s,"??","LBS_NOTIFY",sep);
    if( (style & LBS_SORT) == LBS_SORT )    buildString(s,"??","LBS_SORT",sep);
    if( (style & LBS_USETABSTOPS) == LBS_USETABSTOPS )  buildString(s,"??","LBS_USETABSTOPS",sep);
    if( (style & LBS_WANTKEYBOARDINPUT) == LBS_WANTKEYBOARDINPUT )  buildString(s,"??","LBS_WANTKEYBOARDINPUT",sep);
}

void pushListViewStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & LVS_TYPEMASK) == LVS_REPORT )  buildString(s,"??","LVS_REPORT",sep);
    else if( (style & LVS_TYPEMASK) == LVS_LIST )   buildString(s,"??","LVS_LIST",sep);
    else if( (style & LVS_TYPEMASK) == LVS_SMALLICON )  buildString(s,"??","LVS_SMALLICON",sep);
    else buildString(s,"??","LVS_ICON",sep);

    if( (style & 0x30) == LVS_SORTASCENDING )   buildString(s,"??","LVS_SORTASCENDING",sep);
    else if( (style & 0x30) == LVS_SORTDESCENDING ) buildString(s,"??","LVS_SORTDESCENDING",sep);

    if( (style & LVS_ALIGNLEFT) == LVS_ALIGNLEFT )  buildString(s,"??","LVS_ALIGNLEFT",sep);
    if( (style & LVS_NOCOLUMNHEADER) == LVS_NOCOLUMNHEADER )    buildString(s,"??","LVS_NOCOLUMNHEADER",sep);
    if( (style & LVS_NOSORTHEADER) == LVS_NOSORTHEADER )    buildString(s,"??","LVS_NOSORTHEADER",sep);
    if( (style & LVS_AUTOARRANGE) == LVS_AUTOARRANGE )  buildString(s,"??","LVS_AUTOARRANGE",sep);
    if( (style & LVS_EDITLABELS) == LVS_EDITLABELS )    buildString(s,"??","LVS_EDITLABELS",sep);
    if( (style & LVS_NOLABELWRAP) == LVS_NOLABELWRAP )  buildString(s,"??","LVS_NOLABELWRAP",sep);
    if( (style & LVS_NOSCROLL) == LVS_NOSCROLL )    buildString(s,"??","LVS_NOSCROLL",sep);
    if( (style & LVS_OWNERDATA) == LVS_OWNERDATA )  buildString(s,"??","LVS_OWNERDATA",sep);
    if( (style & LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED) == LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED )    buildString(s,"??","LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED",sep);
    if( (style & LVS_SHAREIMAGELISTS) == LVS_SHAREIMAGELISTS )  buildString(s,"??","LVS_SHAREIMAGELISTS",sep);
    if( (style & LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS) == LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS )  buildString(s,"??","LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS",sep);
    if( (style & LVS_SINGLESEL) == LVS_SINGLESEL )  buildString(s,"??","LVS_SINGLESEL",sep);
}

void pushMonthCalendarControlStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & MCS_DAYSTATE) == MCS_DAYSTATE )    buildString(s,"??","MCS_DAYSTATE",sep);
    if( (style & MCS_MULTISELECT) == MCS_MULTISELECT )  buildString(s,"??","MCS_MULTISELECT",sep);
    if( (style & MCS_WEEKNUMBERS) == MCS_WEEKNUMBERS )  buildString(s,"??","MCS_WEEKNUMBERS",sep);
    if( (style & MCS_NOTODAYCIRCLE) == MCS_NOTODAYCIRCLE )  buildString(s,"??","MCS_NOTODAYCIRCLE",sep);
    if( (style & MCS_NOTODAY) == MCS_NOTODAY )  buildString(s,"??","MCS_NOTODAY",sep);
}

void pushProgressBarStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & PGS_AUTOSCROLL) == PGS_AUTOSCROLL )    buildString(s,"??","PGS_AUTOSCROLL",sep);
    if( (style & PGS_DRAGNDROP) == PGS_DRAGNDROP )  buildString(s,"??","PGS_DRAGNDROP",sep);
    if( (style & PGS_HORZ) == PGS_HORZ )buildString(s,"??","PGS_HORZ",sep);
    if( (style & PGS_VERT) == PGS_VERT )buildString(s,"??","PGS_VERT",sep);
    if( (style & PBS_SMOOTH) == PBS_SMOOTH )    buildString(s,"??","PBS_SMOOTH",sep)
    if( (style & PBS_VERTICAL) == PBS_VERTICAL )    buildString(s,"??","PBS_VERTICAL",sep);
}

void pushReBarStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & RBS_AUTOSIZE) == RBS_AUTOSIZE )    buildString(s,"??","RBS_AUTOSIZE",sep);
    if( (style & RBS_BANDBORDERS) == RBS_BANDBORDERS )  buildString(s,"??","RBS_BANDBORDERS",sep);
    if( (style & RBS_DBLCLKTOGGLE) == RBS_DBLCLKTOGGLE )    buildString(s,"??","RBS_DBLCLKTOGGLE",sep);
    if( (style & RBS_FIXEDORDER) == RBS_FIXEDORDER )    buildString(s,"??","RBS_FIXEDORDER",sep);
    if( (style & RBS_REGISTERDROP) == RBS_REGISTERDROP )    buildString(s,"??","RBS_REGISTERDROP",sep);
    if( (style & RBS_TOOLTIPS) == RBS_TOOLTIPS )    buildString(s,"??","RBS_TOOLTIPS",sep);
    if( (style & RBS_VARHEIGHT) == RBS_VARHEIGHT )  buildString(s,"??","RBS_VARHEIGHT",sep);
    if( (style & RBS_VERTICALGRIPPER) == RBS_VERTICALGRIPPER )  buildString(s,"??","RBS_VERTICALGRIPPER",sep);
}

void pushScrollBarStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & SBS_VERT) == SBS_VERT )buildString(s,"??","SBS_VERT",sep);
}

void pushStaticControlStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & SS_TYPEMASK) == SS_BITMAP )    buildString(s,"??","SS_BITMAP",sep);
    else if( (style & SS_TYPEMASK) == SS_BLACKFRAME )   buildString(s,"??","SS_BLACKFRAME",sep);
    else if( (style & SS_TYPEMASK) == SS_BLACKRECT )    buildString(s,"??","SS_BLACKRECT",sep);
    else if( (style & SS_TYPEMASK) == SS_CENTER )   buildString(s,"??","SS_CENTER",sep);
    else if( (style & SS_TYPEMASK) == SS_ENHMETAFILE )  buildString(s,"??","SS_ENHMETAFILE",sep);
    else if( (style & SS_TYPEMASK) == SS_ETCHEDFRAME )  buildString(s,"??","SS_ETCHEDFRAME",sep);
    else if( (style & SS_TYPEMASK) == SS_ETCHEDHORZ )   buildString(s,"??","SS_ETCHEDHORZ",sep);
    else if( (style & SS_TYPEMASK) == SS_ETCHEDVERT )   buildString(s,"??","SS_ETCHEDVERT",sep);
    else if( (style & SS_TYPEMASK) == SS_GRAYFRAME )    buildString(s,"??","SS_GRAYFRAME",sep);
    else if( (style & SS_TYPEMASK) == SS_GRAYRECT ) buildString(s,"??","SS_GRAYRECT",sep);
    else if( (style & SS_TYPEMASK) == SS_ICON ) buildString(s,"??","SS_ICON",sep);
    else if( (style & SS_TYPEMASK) == SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP )   buildString(s,"??","SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP",sep);
    else if( (style & SS_TYPEMASK) == SS_OWNERDRAW )    buildString(s,"??","SS_OWNERDRAW",sep);
    else if( (style & SS_TYPEMASK) == SS_RIGHT )    buildString(s,"??","SS_RIGHT",sep);
    else if( (style & SS_TYPEMASK) == SS_SIMPLE )   buildString(s,"??","SS_SIMPLE",sep);
    else if( (style & SS_TYPEMASK) == SS_WHITEFRAME )   buildString(s,"??","SS_WHITEFRAME",sep);
    else if( (style & SS_TYPEMASK) == SS_WHITERECT )    buildString(s,"??","SS_WHITERECT",sep);

    if( (style & SS_ELLIPSISMASK) == SS_PATHELLIPSIS )  buildString(s,"??","SS_PATHELLIPSIS",sep);
    else if( (style & SS_ELLIPSISMASK) == SS_WORDELLIPSIS ) buildString(s,"??","SS_WORDELLIPSIS",sep);
    else if( (style & SS_ELLIPSISMASK) == SS_ENDELLIPSIS )  buildString(s,"??","SS_ENDELLIPSIS",sep);

    if( (style & SS_CENTERIMAGE) == SS_CENTERIMAGE )    buildString(s,"??","SS_CENTERIMAGE",sep);
    if( (style & SS_NOPREFIX) == SS_NOPREFIX )  buildString(s,"??","SS_NOPREFIX",sep);
    if( (style & SS_NOTIFY) == SS_NOTIFY )  buildString(s,"??","SS_NOTIFY",sep);
    
    if( (style & SS_REALSIZEIMAGE) == SS_REALSIZEIMAGE )    buildString(s,"??","SS_REALSIZEIMAGE",sep);
    if( (style & SS_RIGHTJUST) == SS_RIGHTJUST )    buildString(s,"??","SS_RIGHTJUST",sep);
    if( (style & SS_SUNKEN) == SS_SUNKEN )  buildString(s,"??","SS_SUNKEN",sep);
}

void pushStatusBarStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & SBARS_SIZEGRIP) == SBARS_SIZEGRIP )    buildString(s,"??","SBARS_SIZEGRIP",sep);
    if( (style & SBT_TOOLTIPS) == SBT_TOOLTIPS )    buildString(s,"??","SBT_TOOLTIPS",sep);
}

void pushTabBarStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & TCS_BOTTOM) == TCS_BOTTOM )    buildString(s,"??","TCS_BOTTOM",sep);
    if( (style & TCS_BUTTONS) == TCS_BUTTONS )  buildString(s,"??","TCS_BUTTONS",sep);
    if( (style & TCS_FIXEDWIDTH) == TCS_FIXEDWIDTH )    buildString(s,"??","TCS_FIXEDWIDTH",sep);
    if( (style & TCS_FLATBUTTONS) == TCS_FLATBUTTONS )  buildString(s,"??","TCS_FLATBUTTONS",sep);
    if( (style & TCS_FOCUSNEVER) == TCS_FOCUSNEVER )    buildString(s,"??","TCS_FOCUSNEVER",sep);
    if( (style & TCS_FOCUSONBUTTONDOWN) == TCS_FOCUSONBUTTONDOWN )  buildString(s,"??","TCS_FOCUSONBUTTONDOWN",sep);
    if( (style & TCS_FORCEICONLEFT) == TCS_FORCEICONLEFT )  buildString(s,"??","TCS_FORCEICONLEFT",sep);
    if( (style & TCS_FORCELABELLEFT) == TCS_FORCELABELLEFT )    buildString(s,"??","TCS_FORCELABELLEFT",sep);
    if( (style & TCS_HOTTRACK) == TCS_HOTTRACK )    buildString(s,"??","TCS_HOTTRACK",sep);
    if( (style & TCS_MULTILINE) == TCS_MULTILINE )  buildString(s,"??","TCS_MULTILINE",sep);
    if( (style & TCS_MULTISELECT) == TCS_MULTISELECT )  buildString(s,"??","TCS_MULTISELECT",sep);
    if( (style & TCS_OWNERDRAWFIXED) == TCS_OWNERDRAWFIXED )    buildString(s,"??","TCS_OWNERDRAWFIXED",sep);
    if( (style & TCS_RAGGEDRIGHT) == TCS_RAGGEDRIGHT )  buildString(s,"??","TCS_RAGGEDRIGHT",sep);
    if( (style & TCS_RIGHT) == TCS_RIGHT )  buildString(s,"??","TCS_RIGHT",sep);
    if( (style & TCS_RIGHTJUSTIFY) == TCS_RIGHTJUSTIFY )    buildString(s,"??","TCS_RIGHTJUSTIFY",sep);
    if( (style & TCS_SCROLLOPPOSITE) == TCS_SCROLLOPPOSITE )    buildString(s,"??","TCS_SCROLLOPPOSITE",sep);
    if( (style & TCS_SINGLELINE) == TCS_SINGLELINE )    buildString(s,"??","TCS_SINGLELINE",sep);
    if( (style & TCS_TABS) == TCS_TABS )buildString(s,"??","TCS_TABS",sep);
    if( (style & TCS_TOOLTIPS) == TCS_TOOLTIPS )    buildString(s,"??","TCS_TOOLTIPS",sep);
    if( (style & TCS_VERTICAL) == TCS_VERTICAL )    buildString(s,"??","TCS_VERTICAL",sep);
}

void pushToolBarStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & TBSTYLE_ALTDRAG) == TBSTYLE_ALTDRAG )  buildString(s,"??","TBSTYLE_ALTDRAG",sep);
    if( (style & TBSTYLE_CUSTOMERASE) == TBSTYLE_CUSTOMERASE )  buildString(s,"??","TBSTYLE_CUSTOMERASE",sep);
    if( (style & TBSTYLE_FLAT) == TBSTYLE_FLAT )    buildString(s,"??","TBSTYLE_FLAT",sep);
    if( (style & TBSTYLE_LIST) == TBSTYLE_LIST )    buildString(s,"??","TBSTYLE_LIST",sep);
    if( (style & TBSTYLE_REGISTERDROP) == TBSTYLE_REGISTERDROP )    buildString(s,"??","TBSTYLE_REGISTERDROP",sep);
    if( (style & TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS) == TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS )    buildString(s,"??","TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS",sep);
    if( (style & TBSTYLE_TRANSPARENT) == TBSTYLE_TRANSPARENT )  buildString(s,"??","TBSTYLE_TRANSPARENT",sep);
    if( (style & TBSTYLE_WRAPABLE) == TBSTYLE_WRAPABLE )    buildString(s,"??","TBSTYLE_WRAPABLE",sep);
}

void pushToolTipStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & TTS_ALWAYSTIP) == TTS_ALWAYSTIP )  buildString(s,"??","TTS_ALWAYSTIP",sep);
    if( (style & TTS_BALLOON) == TTS_BALLOON )  buildString(s,"??","TTS_BALLOON",sep);
    if( (style & TTS_CLOSE) == TTS_CLOSE )  buildString(s,"??","TTS_CLOSE",sep);
    if( (style & TTS_NOANIMATE) == TTS_NOANIMATE )  buildString(s,"??","TTS_NOANIMATE",sep);
    if( (style & TTS_NOFADE) == TTS_NOFADE )    buildString(s,"??","TTS_NOFADE",sep);
    if( (style & TTS_NOPREFIX) == TTS_NOPREFIX )    buildString(s,"??","TTS_NOPREFIX",sep);
}

void pushTrackBarStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & TBS_AUTOTICKS) == TBS_AUTOTICKS )  buildString(s,"??","TBS_AUTOTICKS",sep);
    if( (style & TBS_VERT) == TBS_VERT ) buildString(s,"??","TBS_VERT",sep);
    if( (style & TBS_HORZ) == TBS_HORZ ) buildString(s,"??","TBS_HORZ",sep);
    if( (style & TBS_TOP) == TBS_TOP ) buildString(s,"??","TBS_TOP",sep);
    if( (style & TBS_BOTTOM) == TBS_BOTTOM )    buildString(s,"??","TBS_BOTTOM",sep);
    if( (style & TBS_LEFT) == TBS_LEFT ) buildString(s,"??","TBS_LEFT",sep);
    if( (style & TBS_RIGHT) == TBS_RIGHT ) buildString(s,"??","TBS_RIGHT",sep);
    if( (style & TBS_BOTH) == TBS_BOTH ) buildString(s,"??","TBS_BOTH",sep);
    if( (style & TBS_NOTICKS) == TBS_NOTICKS )  buildString(s,"??","TBS_NOTICKS",sep);
    if( (style & TBS_ENABLESELRANGE) == TBS_ENABLESELRANGE )    buildString(s,"??","TBS_ENABLESELRANGE",sep);
    if( (style & TBS_FIXEDLENGTH) == TBS_FIXEDLENGTH )  buildString(s,"??","TBS_FIXEDLENGTH",sep);
    if( (style & TBS_NOTHUMB) == TBS_NOTHUMB )  buildString(s,"??","TBS_NOTHUMB",sep);
    if( (style & TBS_TOOLTIPS) == TBS_TOOLTIPS )    buildString(s,"??","TBS_TOOLTIPS",sep);
    if( (style & TBS_REVERSED) == TBS_REVERSED )    buildString(s,"??","TBS_REVERSED",sep);
    if( (style & TBS_DOWNISLEFT) == TBS_DOWNISLEFT )    buildString(s,"??","TBS_DOWNISLEFT",sep);
}

void pushTreeViewStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & TVS_CHECKBOXES) == TVS_CHECKBOXES )    buildString(s,"??","TVS_CHECKBOXES",sep);
    if( (style & TVS_DISABLEDRAGDROP) == TVS_DISABLEDRAGDROP )  buildString(s,"??","TVS_DISABLEDRAGDROP",sep);
    if( (style & TVS_EDITLABELS) == TVS_EDITLABELS )    buildString(s,"??","TVS_EDITLABELS",sep);
    if( (style & TVS_FULLROWSELECT) == TVS_FULLROWSELECT )  buildString(s,"??","TVS_FULLROWSELECT",sep);
    if( (style & TVS_HASBUTTONS) == TVS_HASBUTTONS )    buildString(s,"??","TVS_HASBUTTONS",sep);
    if( (style & TVS_HASLINES) == TVS_HASLINES )    buildString(s,"??","TVS_HASLINES",sep);
    if( (style & TVS_INFOTIP) == TVS_INFOTIP )  buildString(s,"??","TVS_INFOTIP",sep);
    if( (style & TVS_LINESATROOT) == TVS_LINESATROOT )  buildString(s,"??","TVS_LINESATROOT",sep);
    if( (style & TVS_NOHSCROLL) == TVS_NOHSCROLL )  buildString(s,"??","TVS_NOHSCROLL",sep);
    if( (style & TVS_NONEVENHEIGHT) == TVS_NONEVENHEIGHT )  buildString(s,"??","TVS_NONEVENHEIGHT",sep);
    if( (style & TVS_NOSCROLL) == TVS_NOSCROLL )    buildString(s,"??","TVS_NOSCROLL",sep);
    if( (style & TVS_NOTOOLTIPS) == TVS_NOTOOLTIPS )    buildString(s,"??","TVS_NOTOOLTIPS",sep);
    if( (style & TVS_RTLREADING) == TVS_RTLREADING )    buildString(s,"??","TVS_RTLREADING",sep);
    if( (style & TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS) == TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS )  buildString(s,"??","TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS",sep);
    if( (style & TVS_SINGLEEXPAND) == TVS_SINGLEEXPAND )    buildString(s,"??","TVS_SINGLEEXPAND",sep);
}

void pushUpDownControlStyle(std::string &s,uint style,const char *sep)
{
    if( (style & UDS_ALIGNLEFT) == UDS_ALIGNLEFT )  buildString(s,"??","UDS_ALIGNLEFT",sep);
    else if( (style & UDS_ALIGNRIGHT) == UDS_ALIGNRIGHT )   buildString(s,"??","UDS_ALIGNRIGHT",sep);

    if( (style & UDS_ARROWKEYS) == UDS_ARROWKEYS )  buildString(s,"??","UDS_ARROWKEYS",sep);
    if( (style & UDS_AUTOBUDDY) == UDS_AUTOBUDDY )  buildString(s,"??","UDS_AUTOBUDDY",sep);
    if( (style & UDS_HORZ) == UDS_HORZ ) buildString(s,"??","UDS_HORZ",sep);
    if( (style & UDS_HOTTRACK) == UDS_HOTTRACK )    buildString(s,"??","UDS_HOTTRACK",sep);
    if( (style & UDS_NOTHOUSANDS) == UDS_NOTHOUSANDS )  buildString(s,"??","UDS_NOTHOUSANDS",sep);
    if( (style & UDS_SETBUDDYINT) == UDS_SETBUDDYINT )  buildString(s,"??","UDS_SETBUDDYINT",sep);
    if( (style & UDS_WRAP) == UDS_WRAP ) buildString(s,"??","UDS_WRAP",sep);
}

Win32ClassList win32_class_list =
{
 {ANIMATE_CLASSA, pushAnimateControlStyle},
 {WC_BUTTONA, pushButtonStyle,},
 {WC_COMBOBOXEXA, pushComboBoxExStyle},
 {WC_COMBOBOXA, pushComboBoxStyle},
 {DATETIMEPICK_CLASSA, pushDateTimePickerStyle},
 {WC_EDITA, pushEditControlStyle},
 {WC_HEADERA, pushHeaderControlStyle},
 {WC_LISTBOXA, pushListBoxStyle},
 {WC_LISTVIEWA, pushListViewStyle},
 {MONTHCAL_CLASSA, pushMonthCalendarControlStyle},
 {PROGRESS_CLASSA, pushProgressBarStyle},
 {REBARCLASSNAMEA, pushReBarStyle},
 {WC_SCROLLBARA, pushScrollBarStyle},
 {WC_STATICA, pushStaticControlStyle},
 {STATUSCLASSNAMEA, pushStatusBarStyle},
 {WC_TABCONTROLA, pushTabBarStyle},
 {TOOLBARCLASSNAMEA, pushToolBarStyle},
 {TOOLTIPS_CLASSA, pushToolTipStyle},
 {TRACKBAR_CLASSA, pushTrackBarStyle},
 {WC_TREEVIEWA, pushTreeViewStyle},
 {UPDOWN_CLASSA,pushUpDownControlStyle},
};

}
```